# jquery tree select all child checkboxes

Tags: json, jquery

I am creating a json tree with checkbox using jquery. Here is my code:

```
<body>
  <div id="regionTree">

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    $(function(){

        var json = [{"ID":1,"Name":"r1","Child":[{"ID":1,"Name":"c1"},{"ID":2,"Name":"c2"}]},{"ID":1,"Name":"r2","Child":[{"ID":1,"Name":"c1"},{"ID":2,"Name":"c2"}]}];
        //debugger;
        var treeString = '';
        treeString+='<ul>';
        $(json).each(function(key, value) {
            treeString+='<li>';
            treeString+='<label><input type="checkbox" class="parent"/>'+value.Name+'</label><br/>';
            //alert(value.Name);
            if(value.Child != undefined && value.Child.length > 0)
            {
                treeString+='<ul>';
                $(value.Child).each(function(key,value){
                    treeString+='<li>';
                    treeString+='<label><input type="checkbox" class="child"/>'+value.Name+'</label><br/>';
                    treeString+='</li>';
                    //alert(value.Name);
                });
                treeString+='</ul>';
            }
            treeString+='</li>';
        });
        treeString+='</ul>';
        $('#regionTree').append(treeString);

        //------
        $('.parent').live('click', function(){
            debugger;
            console.log($(this).find('.child').size());
            $(this).parent().children(':checkbox').prop("checked", true);

        });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

If you copy paste it and open up in FF/Chrome you can see the checkbox tree. I wanted to select all child elements of a node if parent is selected. But for some reason i am not able to get all child checkboxe for a node.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().children(':checkbox').prop("checked", true);
```

the checkbox's parent is the label, not the li.

try:

```
$(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox').prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any ready plugin to create a tree with checkboxes form a JSON source. For example:
https://github.com/AlexLibs/niTree